# Setting persistence off (RDB) only for specific redis db and not the whole redis server

Tags: redis

Since we are using redis for both simple caching and applicative logic (think feed, time series, etc) and I'm experiencing pain with redis persistence to disk (RDB) I would like to run RDB off only for a specific DB (or turn it on only for another specific db). I know I can configure RDB for the whole redis Server in redis.conf , But I couldn't find how (if possible) I can configure it only for a specific db. Is this possible? and how?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, it is not possible. Persistence settings (as well as maxmemory, eviction and several others) are defined for the entire Redis instance. The best practice is to use a dedicated Redis server per database rather than use shared (a.k.a. "numbered") databases. More background on the subject at: https://redislabs.com/blog/benchmark-shared-vs-dedicated-redis-instances